# Oracle SQL TO_DATE - two date formats

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-update

I am trying to update several dates to the end of the month.  However, my table has two separate date formats ('DD-MON-YY' and 'YYYYMMDD').  How can I update both dates in an update statement?  Also, I want the new dates to be in 'YYYYMMDD' format.

```
Update MY_TABLE
set MY_DATE = TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(MY_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')),'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: What you really want, is to save dates in a column of date type.

Comment: The dates are saved as VARCHAR. Do you mean by altering the table instead of just pulling them out using to_date?

Comment: Ad @DavidדודוMarkovitz said, I'd also strongly recommend to store only real `Date(Time)` type values in a DB. Displaying regional-culture date formats is a matter of the UI tier, often even a matter of single user settings in the local O/S

Comment: Understood, the ones with DD-MON-YY are old records in the database.

Answer (score 1):

As David noted in the comments, the "real" solution here would be to add a `date` column and use that. If that's not an option, you could differentiate old data from new data based on the existence of the `-` character:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_date = 
       TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(my_date, CASE WHEN my_date LIKE '%-%' 
                                              THEN 'DD-MON-YY'
                                              ELSE 'YYYYMMDD' 
                                         END)),
                'YYYYMMDD')
```